# Namen des akademischen Beifalls. Name of the German applause in educational institutions

Tags: single-word-request

Wie heißt denn das Klopfen mit den Fingerknöcheln auf dem Tisch, das üblicherweise in den akademischen Kreisen anstatt des Klatschens stattfindet?

---

In Germany (at least), after a (good) lecture or talk, one knocks the table. This replaces the usual applause with the palms. I wonder if this particular ovation has a name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich kenne diese Form des Beifalls nur als *Applaus* und hatte nie den Eindruck, hierzu sei (gegenüber dem Klatschen) ein gesondertes Wort nötig.

Siehe beispielsweise:

- ["Klopfen statt klatschen: Einige der jungen Kinderuni-Studenten wussten bereits, wie ein Uni-Applaus funktioniert. (...) Und so wurde zwar applaudiert – allerdings nicht per Klopfen, sondern doch wieder klatschend."](http://diepresse.com/home/bildung/universitaet/1428894/print.do)
- ["Was übrigens auch beim Applaudieren gilt: In der Uni wird am Ende eines Vortrags aufs Holz geklopft"](http://www.badische-zeitung.de/stilfrage/stilfrage-es-liegt-in-ihrer-hand--90566393.html)

Wenn ich so zurückdenke, bin ich mir übrigens auch gar nicht sicher, ob diese Form des Applauses auf die Universität beschränkt ist, oder vielmehr immer dann auftritt, wo das Publikum an (zumindest harten) Tischen sitzt und man den schallenden Lärm eines in Klatschen bestehenden Applauses vermeiden möchte, um statt dessen eine "akustisch etwas zurückhaltendere" Variante zu verwenden.

Comment: Oder einfach nur zu faul ist, beide Hände zu heben. Beim normalen Applaudieren ist es schwierig mit nur einer Hand zu klatschen. Beim "Studentenapplaus" ist das jedoch sehr einfach.

Comment: Ich habe das Klopfen definitiv erst an der Uni kennengelernt.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde es Akademisches Klopfen oder Begeisterungsklopfen nennen.

Herkunft laut Wikipedia

> In akademischen Kreisen wird statt des Klatschens mit den Fingerknöcheln auf Pulte oder Tische geklopft und äußerst selten zur Verstärkung mit Füßen getrampelt. Dieser Brauch ist wohl eine Umkehrung des Austrommelns der Füxe, eine aus Studentenverbindungen hervorgegangene Art, einen Neuling durch Trommeln mit Stöcken auf den Boden das Missfallen der Burschenschaft wissen zu lassen.